# What is the bottleneck algorithm for medical imaging applications?

Tags: imaging

What is the computational bottleneck algorithm for medical imaging applications? We are trying to figure out if there is a benefit to run these algorithms on regular cloud server instances or GPU accelerated server instances.

Comment: By leveraging products like Matlab Parallel Toolbox, Acceleware AxRecon, or Accelereyes Jacket, application developers get GPU acceleration if available. What the question is about is what the bottleneck operators are so that we can predict our benefit and impact if we change the operators.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the software has been specifically designed with GPU processing power in mind, GPU accelerated instances will be about the same performance as regular commodity server instances, only at a higher price.

I'm willing to gamble and say that the bottleneck of any algorithm, medical or not, imaging or not is the rate at which you can throw data at the CPU, and the number of cores, and the clock rate.

Get some fast CPUs, Insanely fast RAM, blindingly fast striped/mirrored storage, and do it that way.

I suspect that you'll probably find that running on "the cloud" is actually counter-intuitive, or at least counterproductive, as many cloud service providers don't tune their storage backends to cater for high performance computing, but more to providing a little bit of IO to the masses.

I think you'd be better off with owned dedicated hardware, that way, you can spend more time and money in efficiently tuning the hardware stack to match your software stack.  Any cloud service provider (including Amazon) will give you some trade offs and compromises.

Oh, and don't forget about not putting all your [eggs in one basket.](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/where-are-your-eggs-stored/)  What happens when Amazon goes offline, and nobody can examine any X-Rays, or the poor schmuck who put a [heart monitoring application](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/seriously-what/) on Amazon Cloud instances, and Amazon went offline in a massive outage.

Aside from the compromises  of cloud hosting, the problems of being redundant and resilient to provider outages, not putting critical infrastructure on the cloud, there's other questions surrounding the architecture of your application itself.. Will it scale linearly?

I bet it won't.

Comment: Not a helpful answer: the question was an algorithmic one, not a request to comment on cloud folklore. There are plenty of HPC oriented clouds that offer GPU acceleration, to name a few, Nimbix, SGI Cyclone, Sabalcore. So back to the question, what is the bottleneck operator of medical imaging? Is it a constraint solver, an eigen value solver, a PDE solver, spectral operations?

Comment: You should either know your algorithms, or write better questions. Drainwater.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am sorry to have upset you.

Comment: You haven't upset me, you just failed to write a decent question.

Answer (score 0):

By benching a GPU-like implementation against Cloud Server instances, you can see huge [FPS differences](https://www.imagewisely.org/Imaging-Modalities/Fluoroscopy/Modern-Imaging-Systems) [1, 2] for operations on large (*e.g.*, CR) images. However, on the other hand, the GPU can be occupied with a lot of memory and therefore delaying and giving continuously dropouts. Therefore, a Cloud Server solution could be more stable with not as many dropouts and a smoother feeling but with lower FPS.

[1] Zhang, Lequan, et al. "A high-frequency, high frame rate duplex ultrasound linear array imaging system for small animal imaging." IEEE transactions on ultrasonics, ferroelectrics, and frequency control 57.7 (2010).

[2] Miguez, D., et al. "A technical note on variable inter-frame interval as a cause of non-physiological experimental artefacts in ultrasound." Royal Society open science 4.5 (2017): 170245.